# mysqld-nt.exe exist in task list,but actually it's not running?

Tags: mysql, debugging, system-administration

Have you ever step into this kind of problem?

I tried:

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

And it fails to connect.

I can see `mysqld-nt.exe` in the task manager(I'm using windows platform).

So I restarted the server,and it's ok.

This happens every day. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is the error log(I didn't find anything abnormal though):

> 100122 10:11:16 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL
>   Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Normal
>   shutdown
>
> 100122 10:11:16  InnoDB: Starting
>   shutdown... 100122 10:11:18  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence
>   number 0 22939338 100122 10:11:18
>   [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Shutdown complete
>
> 100122 10:12:40  InnoDB: Started; log
>   sequence number 0 22939338 100122
>   10:12:42 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.0.24-community-nt'  socket: '' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Edition
>   (GPL) 100123 16:20:44 [Note]
>   D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Normal shutdown
>
> 100123 16:20:44  InnoDB: Starting
>   shutdown... 100123 16:20:46  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence
>   number 0 22939832 100123 16:20:46
>   [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Shutdown complete
>
> 100123 16:22:09  InnoDB: Started; log
>   sequence number 0 22939832 100123
>   16:22:11 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.0.24-community-nt'  socket: '' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Edition
>   (GPL) 100125  9:18:59 [Note]
>   D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Normal shutdown
>
> 100125  9:18:59  InnoDB: Starting
>   shutdown... 100125  9:19:00  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence
>   number 0 22941001 100125  9:19:00
>   [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Shutdown complete
>
> 100125  9:20:22  InnoDB: Started; log
>   sequence number 0 22941001 100125 
>   9:20:25 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.0.24-community-nt'  socket: '' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Edition
>   (GPL)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the mysqld-nt's network connections are being exhausted hence the telnet fails and a restart cures it, are you using too many connections, try increasing the connections allowed/permitted for the server itself.

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: No,I tried yerterday to increase the maximium connection,but it still happens.And in fact it's not published yet,so there should be too many concurrent connections.

Comment: Also I've checked if there is some scheduled tasks by `at`,but found nothing.